# ASP.NET Password Strength Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm using the ASP.NET Membership property for authentication on my ASP.NET website.  I want the passwords to be pretty secure.  I want them to be 7 digits long, containing a letter, number, and a special character.

[I found this to be added to the web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordstrengthregularexpression%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression=" @\"(?=.{6,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})"
```

However, when I add this to my Membership profile, I get the following error:

```
Name cannot begin with the '(' character, hexadecimal value 0x28. Line 26, position 445.
```

So it looks like it's not seeing the escape character after the @ symbol, and it's trying to use that quote to end the tag.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Lastly, how would I modify this to also require a lower case letter and an upper case letter?

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
ValidationExpression="(?=^.{7,51}$)([A-Za-z]{1})([A-Za-z0-9!@#$%_\^\&amp;\*\-\.\?]{5,49})$"
```

[Here](http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) you can find lot of samples

Comment: Don't believe that will work, as it will match against `helloth`

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to escape the `"` and this is in your web.config file, you need to do `&quot;`, that is the proper quote entity for xml.  As for the regex you want, try this

```
^(?=[a-z]+)(?=.*?\d+)(?=.*?[`~!@#$%^&*\(\)\-_}{\]\[=+\\|]+).{7,}$
```

Will match against the following items in bold

- helloth
- hellot
- hell0th
- hell0Th
- **he!l0th**
- **he!l0Th**
- **he!l0Th3534534**
- **he!l0Thdggfsg**

You can add `(?=.*?[A-Z]+)` if you also want to require at least one upper case letter, and make it only match the last 3.  Finally, you can modify the following block from the regex above to include only the special chars you want to allow.

```
[`~!@#$%^&*\(\)\-_}{\]\[=+\\|]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with an expression no one understands, use three (or more). There following is some pseudo code for this idea:

```
abort('to short') if password.length < 8
abort('at least one letter') if password !~ /[a-z]/i
abort('at least two digits') if password !~ /[0-9].*[0-9]/
abort('at least one special character') if password !~ /[!@#$%^\*-=\+\?]/
```

Answer (score -1):

'Added by [Itrend solutions](http://www.itrendsolutions.com) -Password Validation

Create a method and pass your text to validate the password strength ..
Dim password AsString
password = Trim(txtnewpassword.Text)

DimSmallCharacter() AsString = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}
DimsmallchacountAsInteger = 0
ForEachsmallchaAsStringInSmallCharacter
If (password.Contains(smallcha)) Then
smallchacount = smallchacount + 1
EndIf
Next
Ifsmallchacount<= 0 Then
MessageBox("Password Must Contain One Alphabet Character")
Exit Sub
EndIf

Dim Numbers() AsString = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
DimnumbercountAsInteger = 0
ForEachnumAsStringIn Numbers
If (password.Contains(num)) Then
numbercount = numbercount + 1
EndIf
Next
Ifnumbercount<= 0 Then
MessageBox("Password Must Contain One Numeric Digit")
Exit Sub
EndIf

DimSpecial() AsString = {"@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "!"}
DimcountSpecialAsInteger = 0
ForEach spec AsStringIn Special
If (password.Contains(spec)) Then
countSpecial = countSpecial + 1
EndIf
Next
IfcountSpecial<= 0 Then
MessageBox("Password Must Contain One Special Character")
Exit Sub

for More clarification please [contact us](http://www.itrendsolutions.com)

Comment: ya its working fine to validate the password strength in vb.net

Comment: Very broken formatting, please edit.